# Clicar sobre a barra de títulos e não ordenar a coluna no dataTables

Tags: datatable

Bom dia. Estou usando o dataTables e em uma das colunas eu coloquei um input:checkbox para o usuário poder marcar ou desmarcar todas colunas, lembrando que nas colunas eu tenho como fazer a ordenação quando clica na barra de título e nessa coluna também tem isso. Até ai tudo funcionando. O que não estou sabendo como fazer é que, quando o usuário clica no checkbox não faça a ordenação, somente fazer essa ordenação, pois quando ele clica para marcar ou desmarcar já faz a ordenação, e isso que não pode acontecer. Como faço para tirar a ordenação apenas desta coluna?

[image: print]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode desabilitar o ordenamento da primeira coluna com:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    {
      "orderable": false, 
      "targets": 0
    }
  ]
});
```

De uma olhada na [documentação](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable) para mais opções

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda Guilherme. Resolvi da seguinte forma: 

"columnDefs": [ {
                        "targets": [ 0, 10 ],
                        "orderable": false
                    } ]

Comment: Se o problema foi resolvido aceite essa reposta